# GitLab Plugin SonarQube MR Analysis

Tags: gradle, merge, sonarqube, gitlab-ci, sonarqube-scan

I am using the **free** GitLab and SonarQube Version (6.6.7) on a Java-Gradle Project.

Is there a free GitLab plugin for SonarQube Pull request analysis, similar to https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/pull-request/?

My goal is to block the merge request if new SonarQube issues have been implemented.

(Note: upgrading to SonarQube Developer Edition is not possible)

Answer (score 0):

In the end, you will need to upgrade Sonarqube to a more recent version, to get this working, as it relies on the branch plugin from sonarqube.

There is an open source alternative https://github.com/mc1arke/sonarqube-community-branch-plugin - but this may diverge from the original implementation in some point in time.

The other thing, what you might want to investigate in, is `sonar.qualitygate.wait` as described [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/gitlab-cicd/) - as this would fail your build, which should normally prevent you from merging. I am not sure in which version this property was introduced, but it looks like the easier solution, compared to an upgrade of sonarQube and using the community branch plugin